# Blazor (.NET 8) button onclick is not working when the page is in StreamRendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Good day everyone

I'm trying to use a button click on the weather app, but it seems it's not working when it is set to StreamRendering

But the button onclick is working when I set it to "rendermode" to "InteractiveServer", my only problem with this is when running on the first time, and I click the weather link, it will take like 1 to 2 seconds before the page load, while in streamrendering, it renders the page immediately while loading the data.

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

1. in the "counter.razor" delete "@rendermode InteractiveServer"
2. in the "weather.razor" bottom,add

```
<Counter @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)"/>
```

Test
[image]

Or if you only want to put the button codes in the same page of weather,you could add the "noprender-interactiveserver" and stream render at the same time.

```
@page "/weather"
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
@attribute [StreamRendering]
```

Comment: ok but you're not using Stream rendering anymore you're using interactiveserver?!